# Declaring PHP array items before array loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I was wondering if there was a way that I can declare a variable at the top of my php file that contains some 'array stuff' and have it used in a foreach loop below somewhere?
For example:

```
$variable = 'Here is some text, and here is the value:'.$items->value.'.';


foreach ( $somearray as $items ) {
echo $variable;
}
```

*note: I am using ezsql for database actions, hence the $items->value variable....

Make sense? I'm just trying to make my file easy to change for other situations... or is there a better way?

Thanks for looking and for your help.

Comment: Nope. You could define some `$startvar` & `$endvar` and use `echo $startvar.$item->value.$endvar;` to increase readability (no better performance), or create a mini_template for for instance `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest way to do this would, I think, be [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php). It's not exactly what you asked for, but I think it will make your code cleaner.

```
$variable = 'Here is some text, and here is the value:%s.';

foreach ($somearray as $items) {
    printf($variable, $items->value);
}
```

The value passed as the second argument to `printf` will be substituted into the code.

Comment: That actually works beautifully! Thanks everyone for the help! It was very informative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()`, but you should be aware it's risky, and you better read about the consequences of using it.

Other than that, you can use it like you said, but escape the dollar sign so it won't get treated as a variable until the foreach, or use single quotes:

```
$variable = 'Here is some text, and here is the value: {$items->value}';

foreach ( $somearray as $items ) {
    echo eval('return "'.$variable.'";');
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because `eval` accepts PHP code as input (as opposed to a string literal like in your example). This will result in a parse error. The "proper" way would be `eval('return "'.$variable.'";');`. Although, yes it's risky and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @netcoder: Thanks, you're right I forgot the `return` bit of it. Updated the answer, and yep I'm on the same opinion with you on the eval() deal.

Answer (score 1):

> or is there a better way?

Use a function/method:

```
function formatItems($items)
{
    return 'Here is some text, and here is the value:'.$items->value.'.';
}

foreach ( $somearray as $items ) {
    echo formatItems($items);
}
```

Using a function allows more complex formatting. If it's going to be as simple as your example, you could use [printf](http://php.net/function.printf), [as suggested by lonesomeday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272149/#answer-6272288).

If appropriate, you could have a display/format method in your Items class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$items` variable will be overwritten by your for loop - `$variable` won't be though.

Answer (score -1):

$variable is set only once and takes on the value of $items->value at the time (which will probably result in an error since $items doesn't exist at that time and you are referencing a field.

what you want is this:

```
$variable = 'Here is some text, and here is the value: {$items->value}';

foreach ( $somearray as $items ) {
echo $variable;
}
```

Comment: @Wrikken :) Yeah, yeah, I realized that after the fact.  I deleted my comment.  :).  So, why doesn't it work again?  I'm at work and I don't have WAMP installed here so I can't test but I swear I've used that construct before.  Maybe it was because I was using a template engine?

Comment: Once a string is a string, it will not get magically reinterpreted, but stay a string (and good too, how else would we ever preserve a `$` sign in a string?). To make it work, it would have to be re-interpreted by something. Indeed, by for instance a template engine, or the very evil eval @Dvir is mentioning, which is not be recommended but _does_ work :).

Comment: @Wrikken ah good point about the $ symbol.  I blame Smarty for instilling bad habits :)